# 500 internal server error in ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am trying to post form values using ajax..but i got 500 internal error..

here is my ajax code:

```
    $(function(){
    $( "#submit_enquiry" ).click(function(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      var date= $("#date").val();
      var candidate_id= $("#candidate_id").val();
      var user_id= $("#user_id").val();
      var req_id= $("#req_id").val();
      var status_type_id= $("#status_type_id").val();
      var interview_type_id= $("#interview_type_id").val();   
      var url = "http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Candidate/candidate_process" ;
      $.ajax(
      {
      type:"POST",
      // url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Candidate/candidate_process",
      //url:"http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Candidate/candidate_process" ,
      url: url,
      data:{
      'date':date,
      'candidate_id':candidate_id,
      'user_id':user_id,
      'req_id':req_id,
      'status_type_id':status_type_id,
      'interview_type_id':interview_type_id

      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

});

});
```

Button code:

```
 <button type="submit" id="submit_enquiry" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Schedule Next Round</button><br></br>
```

Can anyone help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: just send /Candidate/candidate_process in url and check once

Comment: no error is coming..but my values are not stored in database..

Comment: Check if you are getting those data in that function in post

Comment: ya i am getting that post data in my console post

Comment: candidate_id 
134
date 
2017-03-04
interview_type_id 
1
req_id 
600
status_type_id 
7
user_id 
62

Comment: If you are getting data, then you can save it to database right ?

Comment: yes..but it's not save in my databas..

Comment: So thats different issue, once go through documentation of CI to work around with it, if seriosly faces any problem, most welcome!

Comment: ok..thank you..rahul_m

Comment: @user3663 is this solved ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam no..it's not solved

Comment: @user3663 give me 3hr time I'll inspect this. Now on mobile

Comment: yeah..ok @AbdullaNilam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `<form>` tag not defined with `action= ""` (shoud be empty)

**In AJAX**

```
$(function(){
    $( "#submit_enquiry" ).click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

        var date= $("#date").val();
        var candidate_id= $("#candidate_id").val();
        var user_id= $("#user_id").val();
        var req_id= $("#req_id").val();
        var status_type_id= $("#status_type_id").val();
        var interview_type_id= $("#interview_type_id").val();   

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/candidate/candidate_process",
            data:{
                'date':date,
                'candidate_id':candidate_id,
                'user_id':user_id,
                'req_id':req_id,
                'status_type_id':status_type_id,
                'interview_type_id':interview_type_id
            },
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hence `base_url()` should be `http://stackoverflow.com/` end `/` is required ...

**In Controller**

```
public function candidate_process()
{
    # to check all inputs are comming.
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

if above code shows all the data then, use the rest of codes

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: you're writing a php statement inside js code?

Comment: @gumuruh does it matter? explain what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

Change your script like this

```
$("#submit_enquiry").click(function(event){
  var date= $("#date").val();
  var candidate_id= $("#candidate_id").val();
  var user_id= $("#user_id").val();
  var req_id= $("#req_id").val();
  var status_type_id= $("#status_type_id").val();
  var interview_type_id= $("#interview_type_id").val();   
  var url = "http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Candidate/candidate_process" ;
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: url,
    data:{
      'date':date,
      'candidate_id':candidate_id,
      'user_id':user_id,
      'req_id':req_id,
      'status_type_id':status_type_id,
      'interview_type_id':interview_type_id
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(data){
       console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```